# Is it possible to exceed sound speed through dilatant fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

As the velocity (and the produced shear stress) of an accelerated object through a dilatant fluid increases, it reacts with a non-linear dilatant behavior which impedes further acceleration at a certain point (the fluid cracks, similarly to silly putty). The question is: is that of a pulse (the speed of sound) the maximum speed possible through a dilatant fluid? I think "yes" but I can't find any paper on this issue.

Comment: I wonder if the answer can be yes or no for all cases, it may depend on how much non-Newtonian the fluid is. At the limit when the fluid gets Newtonian, obviously the speed of sound can be exceeded. On the opposite extreme side, if the viscosity becomes infinite when the rate shear strain increases up to a given value, the speed of sound may not be attained. So there must be a threshold where the answer to the question changes from "no" to "yes".